# Testing equality of higher moments (e.g., kurtosis)

Tags: distributions, moments, kurtosis

I have two large samples which I expected to both be approximately normal, yet one has much greater excess kurtosis. Is there a way to test the likelihood of observing such a difference in kurtosis (i.e., is there a sampling distribution for kurtosis) under the assumption these distributions are equally distributed?

Comment: There is probably an analytical method, but why bother when you can just bootstrap?  Simply take draws with replacement from each distribution, compute sample kurtosis, and save to form a distribution of kurtosis.  Compare, perhaps by computing the portion of the density of the distributions that overlap.